# Manipulating a copy of a numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to manipulate a copy of a matrix, as follows.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.matrix([[4, 1, -1, 1], [1, 4, -1, -1], [-1, -1, 5, 1], [1, -1, 1, 3]])

B = A

B[0, 0] = 0
```

This would change 00-entry of A to 0 as well, but I don't want this to happen. I tried it with np.array() as well, but the same thing happens again. I think this is because A and B are pointing to the same spot in the memory.

I'd appreciate it if anyone let's me know how to prevent A from changing, while B is changed.

Comment: `B = A` never creates a copy in python no matter what objects `A` and `B` refer to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are completely right, `A` and `B` point to the same memory allocation in your case.
`numpy` has a copy function for that what you want to achieve:

```
B = np.copy(A)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `B = A`, B is just a reference to the already existing array `A`. NumPy doesn't copy straight ahead for efficiency reasons.

So, you should use the `arr.copy()` to copy the contents of the array as in:

```
In [9]: B = A.copy()                                                                                                                                                                                               

In [10]: A                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Out[10]: 
matrix([[ 4,  1, -1,  1],
        [ 1,  4, -1, -1],
        [-1, -1,  5,  1],
        [ 1, -1,  1,  3]])

# update an entry in array `B`
In [11]: B[0, 0] = 0                                                                                                                                                                                               

# A is unaffected
In [12]: A                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Out[12]: 
matrix([[ 4,  1, -1,  1],
        [ 1,  4, -1, -1],
        [-1, -1,  5,  1],
        [ 1, -1,  1,  3]])

# change happens only in array B
In [13]: B                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Out[13]: 
matrix([[ 0,  1, -1,  1],
        [ 1,  4, -1, -1],
        [-1, -1,  5,  1],
        [ 1, -1,  1,  3]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  B[:] = A
```

This will make a deep copy

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the copy of the object. You can do this with [numpy.copy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html) since you are working with a numpy object.

So, your code will be like so:

```
B = np.copy(A)
```

There are two kinds of copy used with python.

> A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in the original.
>
> A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.

They work independent of object type.

```
from copy import copy, deepcopy

# Shallow copy
b= copy(a)

# Deep copy of object
b= deepcopy(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that right now your B and A are referencing the same spot in the memory. For your problem I would recommend

```
 numpy.matrix.copy
```

check out the documentation here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.copy.html

There is an example there with exactly what you are looking for:

```
x = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], order='F')
y = x.copy()

x.fill(0)

x =  array([[0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0]])
y = array([[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]])
```